# How to determine the length of "Content-Length: " in HTTP packet

Tags: c, http, http-headers

I'm writing code for an http server on an embedded target.  I want to parse the raw HTTP packet I am receiving for its' content length.  My problem arises from the fact that I don't know how many bytes the content length is.  For example, 
//Content-Length is 4 characters
Content-Length: 1000

//Content-Length is 2 characters
Content-Length: 20

My code is:

```
(buf is a char array with the contents of the http data, pLength is a char *)
pLength = strstr(buf, lenTok);
//advance pointer past "Content-Length: " to point to data
if (pLength != NULL) 
    pLength = (pLength + 16);
int length = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < /*length of Content-Length:*/; i++)
{
    length = length * 10;
    length = length + (pLength[i] - '0');
}
```

I know my code works because for now I have put a hard coded value in the loop iterator condition.  I just need to be able to determine it at run time.

EDIT: Would it be safe to keep reading characters until \r is found?

Comment: read rfc2616, the header has fixed format (but note that malicious requests can be sent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each line in the header ends with a CR/LF pair per [section 3 of RFC7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3). In section 3.2.4 of the same document, it says that *"a field value might be preceded and/or followed by optional whitespace"*.  Therefore to parse the content-length successfully, your code must skip any leading whitespace, then process digits until a whitespace character is found. In other words

```
int i;
int count = 0;
int length = 0;

for ( i = 0; isspace( pLength[i] ); i++ )
{
    // skip leading whitespace
}

for ( count = 1; !isspace( pLength[i] ); i++, count++ )
{
    if ( count > 9 || !isdigit( pLength[i] ) )
    {
        // some sort of error handling is needed here
    }
    length = length * 10;
    length = length + (pLength[i] - '0');
}
```

Note that checking for `count > 9` limits the content-length to 999,999,999. Adjust as necessary for your application. For example, you can support larger numbers if `int` is 64-bits. On the other hand, maybe you only want to support smaller lengths, in which case you could limit the number of digits to a smaller value.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to simply start counting from after the fixed-length string "Content-Length: " until you find either whitespace or a null byte (in some rare conditions).

```
#define INITIAL_LENGTH (16) /* Length of the string "Content-Length: " */

if (pLength == NULL)
    return /* or whatever */
else
    pLength += INITIAL_LENGTH

int length;
for(length = 0; *pLength != 0 && *pLength != '\n'; ++pLength)
    length++;

pLength -= length; /* Now it points right after Content-Length:  */
/* Now you have the length */
```

Comment: That `||` should be `&&`, and frankly it should be utilizing `isdigit` imho.

Comment: Corrected that. @WhozCraig: I could have also used `isspace` from ctypes but I didn't want to complicate an easy example ..

Comment: ... except that the terminating character will be a SP, TAB, or CR character, and never a NUL or LF character.